# Good strategy for testing a lot of reads on the same data with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I am testing a class, with RSpec, that reads data from the database. Depending on arguments, it will not return the same.

My current strategy is something like this:

```ruby
before do
  # create a bunch of data
end

it 'test1' # ...
it 'test2' # ...
it 'test3' # ...
```

Which of course means that my data will be created before each test.

I would like to be able to create the data once, in the scope of this file, and do my reads on the data.

I tried setting `use_transactional_fixtures` to false for the file and use database_cleaner but it made my tests twice as slow because I had to re-seed my db before and after the tests.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell rspec "run each of these tests in the same transaction".

Or maybe, since I'm having a hard time finding that, there's a better strategy for that kind of testing?

Comment: What's wrong with just putting it all in the same `it`? Or perhaps using stubs instead of using the database at all?

Comment: I considered that, and it may be what I'll end up doing, but it's a workaround and not really a "clean" solution. It also feels like it removes the "unit" from unit testing.  

It also prevents from leveraging the full power of RSpec such as the `context`s

Comment: You should really look at these as integration tests since they are hitting a db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using the database_cleaner gem was the right thing to do, I was just doing it wrong. I had set my cleaning strategy to truncation which emptied the db...

On this Github issue, David Chelimsky explains that using database_cleaner is the way to go https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/issues/2

My tests now look like this:

```
  before(:all) do
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

    DatabaseCleaner.start
    create_data
  end

  after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  def create_data
    # create the data...
  end

  it 'test1' # ...
  it 'test2' # ...
  it 'test3' # ...
end
```

The same tests now run in ~3.5s versus ~7s before. I am happy :)

edit: one before :all is enough

Comment: Is that really a before :all loop inside a before :all loop? In each individual test? Or is this in spec_helper?

Comment: Good catch! The first before :all was not supposed to be there. (edited the code). I put that in the something_spec.rb file because it's something I want to only happen there. If I need similar functionality in another file, I'll move that piece to an RSpec config and include it if some metadata key is present.